# Subir archivos al servidor con Flask y Python (error si no subes el archivo)

Tags: python, servidor, flask

**¿Cómo puedo hacer que no muestre el mensaje de error hasta que no sea necesario, y no permanentemente como lo hace con este código?
Si hay algún fallo en el .html, no es que esté mal, es que he recortado cosas por no hacer tan largo el mensaje. Saludos y gracias de antemano ;)**

(En archivo.html)

```
<html>
   <body>
       <h2>Herramientas</h2>
           <div class="table">
               <h1>Sube tu archivo!</h1>
               <form action="/subidaarchivos" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <input type="file" name="archivo" multiple>
                   <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar archivo/s"></p>
                   <div class="msg">{{ msg }}</div>
               </form>
           </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

(En archivo config.py)

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, session, request
import MySQLdb.cursors
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './Archivos subidos'

@app.route("/subidaarchivos", methods=['POST','GET'])
def subidaarchivos():
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.files['archivo']:
        # obtenemos el archivo del input "archivo"
        f = request.files['archivo']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        # Guardamos el archivo en el directorio "Archivos PDF"
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        # Retornamos una respuesta satisfactoria
        msg = 'Se ha enviado correctamente!'
        return render_template('subidaarchivos.html', msg=msg)
    else:
        msg = 'Se ha producido un error!'
        return render_template('subidaarchivos.html', msg=msg)
´´´
```

Comment: Al poner la cláusula `else` de esa forma, estás enviando el error cada vez que se carga la página (cuando hay un GET), por eso es que lo ves siempre.

Comment: @César Claro, llevas razón, cambiaré eso entonces. Muchísimas gracias!!